# How can I get an h1 element to display over an image?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to display my page's title, "Math Achievement Tutoring", over a photograph of a hiker. My first attempt was to create this html:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
      <header>
          <h1>Math Achivement Tutoring</h1>
      </header>
      <div id="hero">
          <img src="http://michaelmossey.com/demo/home-hiker-grayish.jpg" alt="" width="500">
     </div>
</div>
```

with this CSS, the idea being to position the h1 as absolute:

```
h1 { 
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  color: #a04040;
}
```

but this means the title is no longer centered. I may run into other trouble as well if I start to fiddle with margin and padding.

```css
   h1 { 
      text-align:center;
      position: absolute;
      color: #a04040;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
      <header>
          <h1>Math Achivement Tutoring</h1>
      </header>
      <div id="hero">
          <img src="http://michaelmossey.com/demo/home-hiker-grayish.jpg" alt="" width="500">
     </div>
</div>
```

What are my options for achieving this, and does it depend on where I want to take this website eventually? (like adding a navigation menu below the image)? Is there any simple demonstration code?

Comment: Absolute positioning means the width of the element is calculated as shrink-to-fit. If you don’t want that - then _specify_ the width.

Comment: that does fix it and seems like the simplest way to alter what I have done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Div with text over image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585920/div-with-text-over-image)

Answer (score 0):

First, add position relative to #wrapper, then :

if you want it to be vertically & horizontally centered

```
h1 { 
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  color: #a04040;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
}
```

if you want it to be vertically centered

```
h1 { 
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  color: #a04040;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
}
```

if you want it to be horizontally centered

```
h1 { 
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  color: #a04040;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX( -50% );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Loesh Gupta says: make the wrapper `.wrapper { position: relative; }`. To center the text you can use multiple options. I'd go with something like this:
`h1 { position: absolute; left: 50%; right: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }`

I can also recommend this tool: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using flexbox:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;            /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: column;   /* stack flex items vertically */
  position: relative;       /* establish neares positioned ancenstor for absolute positioning */
  
}
h1 {
  color: red;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.center-aligned {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="center-aligned">
  <img class="background-image" src="http://michaelmossey.com/demo/home-hiker-grayish.jpg" />
  <div class="text"><h1>Math Achivement Tutoring<h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a background image on a div and a display flex on the text might do it. Make sure to add the height on the text based on the image so it can be centered.

```css
*{margin: 0 auto;}
.bg{
  background-image:url('http://michaelmossey.com/demo/home-hiker-grayish.jpg');
  height: 380px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.bg h1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 380px;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
<h1>Math Achivement Tutoring</h1>
</div>
```