# Text centered inside the image

Tags: html, css, image, sass

```html
<div>
  <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <span style="">Product</span>
</div>
```

I need it like this and it must be responsiveness too. Can you tell me how to do that?

[image]

Comment: So you have tried nothing?

Comment: Hope you can see the js fiddle above? @Justinas

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585920/div-with-text-over-image

Comment: Put text as `position: absolute` or image as background

Comment: Centering stuff using CSS in all possible ways has been discussed to death already ... https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/, https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this question has been asked many times before, here's a snippet from a duplicate I've answered in the past. Hope you can work your own code into the example shown :)

```css
div.counter {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.counter span {
    position: absolute;    
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div.counter span:before {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   height: 100%;
   content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
    <span>Product</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please vote the answer that helped you the most as the correct one :) Would help us all out! (hopefully mine) @Sampath

Comment: Can you tell me why this line `content: '';`?

Comment: If the content attribute is not set to 'none' or as I've written it, ' ' - the pseudo element, the 'Product' text in this case, will not be generated. Read more about the content property here :) 
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-css-content-property/

Comment: Can you tell me how to break a text automatically if it's not fit to the content? Now it doesn't show balance content and try to show all on a single line.Any trick?

Answer (score 1):

below is code what will do that for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Center Align Elements</h2>
<p>To horizontally center a block element (like div), use margin: auto;</p>

<div class="center">
  <p><b>Note: </b>Using margin:auto will not work in IE8, unless a !DOCTYPE is declared.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just put **background-image** property inside of div style.

Comment: also, this code is pasted from w3schools. I'm pasting link for it:https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_container

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put text as `position: absolute;`. Another is to put image as background.

```css
#sample-1 img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#sample-1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#sample-1 span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 20px;
}

#sample-2 {
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/60x60');
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sample-2 span {
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample-1">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <span>Product</span>
</div>

<div id="sample-2">
  <span>Product 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/xbLqsk7q/2/)

```
<div class="demo">
 <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
 <span style="">Product</span>
</div>
```

css

```
.demo {
 width:200px;
 position:relative;
}
.demo span{
 position:absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: -9px auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in this i have seted line height equals to div height and it is responsive also

```css
#imgContainer{
  background: url(https://placehold.it/60x60);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 }
 #imgDesc{
  top: 50%;
        position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<div id="imgContainer">
   <span id="imgDesc">Works.</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.image {
    position:relative;
}

.image img {
  width:300px;
}
.text {
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top: 100px;
    width: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/60x60"/>
    <div class="text">
      Text
    </div>
</div>
```